# Get/Keep Previous Page's URL with SmoothState

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, smoothstate.js

I am using https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js and trying to create an if/else statement using the previous page's URL. I tried storing the pathname in a cookie, but I also need to use the current pathname and it was only logging the cookie for some reason.

I hope this explains what I'm trying to do:

```
(function($) {
'use strict';
var $page = $('#main'),
    options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        onBefore: function($currentTarget, $container) {

            // Keep the current page's pathname. Specifically
            // check if it's the sites index

        },
        onStart: {
            duration: 1000,
            render: function ($container) {
                $('#tempWrapper').remove();

                // Check if the new page is the site's index or not
                // and run a specific function

                if ( window.location.pathname == "/" ) {
                    smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
                } else {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
                    $(".carousel").remove();                

                    var $newContainer = $container.clone();             
                    $newContainer.attr("id", "tempWrapper");
                    $newContainer.css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:$container.offset().top,
                        width:$container.css("width"),
                        maxHeight:"100vh",
                        overflow:"hidden"
                    });

                    // $container.empty(); 
                    $container.before($newContainer);
                    $('#inner-content').removeClass('entering'); 

                    var element = $('#inner-content', $newContainer);
                    setTimeout(callAnimation(element, true), 0);
                }
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 1000,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                $container.html($newContent);

                // This is where it gets tricky: I need to check if
                // the previous page was the site's index. If the
                // previous page was a subpage, it does an animation.

                if ( window.location.pathname == "/" ) {
                    // Index (home) page
                } else {
                    // Do animations
                    var element = document.getElementById($container[0].id).getElementsByClassName('move')[0];
                    callAnimation(element);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
 })(jQuery);
```

I've inlined my notes, any help is greatly appreciated. I've also tried using document.referrer but displays blank; I'm assuming it's because there's no click page refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written the very same thing. Have a look at the following:

```
(function($) {
'use strict';

var state = {
    source: '',
    bearing: ''
};

var wp = {
    homeUrl: 'http://www.example.com/'
};

/**
 * Get the slug from a full URL.
 * @param  string url
 * @return string
 */
function getSlug( url ) {
    // Remove home URL
    url = url.replace( new RegExp( wp.homeUrl, 'g' ), '' );

    // Remove file extensions
    url = url.replace( /\.[^/.]+$/, '' );

    return ( '' === url || 'index' === url ) ? '/' : url;
}

/**
 * Check if a journey is from a page to another page.
 * @param  string|array  source  The page you are coming from.
 * @param  string|array  bearing The page you are going to.
 * @return boolean
 */
function isJourney( source, bearing ) {
    // Convert array params into strings
    if ( Array.isArray(source) ) {
        source = source.join();
    }

    if ( Array.isArray(bearing) ) {
        bearing = bearing.join();
    }

    return -1 !== source.indexOf( state.source ) && -1 !== bearing.indexOf( state.bearing );
}

var $page = $('#main'),
    options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        onBefore: function($currentTarget, $container) {

            // Keep the current page's pathname. Specifically
            // check if it's the sites index
            var smoothState = $container.smoothState().data('smoothState');

            // Store where you're coming from and where you're going
            state.source = getSlug( smoothState.href );
            state.bearing = getSlug( $currentTarget.get(0).href );

        },
        onStart: {
            duration: 1000,
            render: function ($container) {
                $('#tempWrapper').remove();

                // Check if the new page is the site's index or not
                // and run a specific function

                if ( '/' == state.bearing ) {
                    smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
                } else {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
                    $(".carousel").remove();                

                    var $newContainer = $container.clone();             
                    $newContainer.attr("id", "tempWrapper");
                    $newContainer.css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:$container.offset().top,
                        width:$container.css("width"),
                        maxHeight:"100vh",
                        overflow:"hidden"
                    });

                    // $container.empty(); 
                    $container.before($newContainer);
                    $('#inner-content').removeClass('entering'); 

                    var element = $('#inner-content', $newContainer);
                    setTimeout(callAnimation(element, true), 0);
                }
            }
        },
        onReady: {
            duration: 1000,
            render: function ($container, $newContent) {
                $container.html($newContent);

                // This is where it gets tricky: I need to check if
                // the previous page was the site's index. If the
                // previous page was a subpage, it does an animation.

                if ( '/' == state.source ) {
                    // Index (home) page
                } else {
                    // Do animations
                    var element = document.getElementById($container[0].id).getElementsByClassName('move')[0];
                    callAnimation(element);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
 })(jQuery);
```

Place your home page URL in the `wp.homeUrl` variable. This can be done with [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) when adding the script file, if you'd rather not hardcode it.

Then you can check the state variable to see which page you came from (`source`) or are going to (`bearing`).

I've also thrown in a quick `isJourney()` function that I wrote, which allows you to quickly check if you're going from a specific page to another specific page. It supports arrays in either parameter, so you can test if going from a page to a set of pages.

Hope this helps!

PS - if anyone knows a better way to get the slug from the URL let me know!